# Problem with sorted phone numbers from hackerrank

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, list-comprehension

I know my attempt is very basic, so is my knowledge of python.
the problem asks for getting multiple numbers from user and remove possible 0, +91, or 91 from their left side to make them 10 digit and then sort and print them.

I tried `num_list[1] = num_list[1][len(num_list[1])-10:]`. It works, so I tried to put it in list comprehension format I'm just studying, but it is not working then. I need help with how to do it hopefully to get a better understanding of when the comprehension format is supposed to be employed.

```
n = int(input()) # get number of phone numbers from user
num_list = [] # an empty list to store phone numbers in
num_list = [input() for _ in range(n)] # store phone numbers in num_list
##################################
num_list = [num_list[num] = num_list[num][len(num_list[num])-10:] for num in num_list]  #remove  possible 0, +91, 91 from beginning of numbers
########################################
num_list = sorted(num_list)
num_list = ["+91 "+num[:5]+" "+num[5:] for num in num_list]
print(*num_list , sep="\n")
```

Comment: List comprehensions evaluate an expression a put all of the results into a list. The assignment statement `num_list[num] = num_list[num][len(num_list[num])-10:]` is not an expression, it's a statement.

Comment: For slice notation, the `len(num_list[num])` is redundant - Python automatically adds it when you use a negative index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't assign directly within a list comprehension.

The syntax that you're looking for is:

```py
num_list = [num[-10:] for num in num_list]
```

which is logically equivalent to:

```py
cleaned_list = []
for num in num_list:
    cleaned_list.append(num[-10:])
num_list = cleaned_list
```